# Firebug pauses on JQuery script with play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

When I refresh my page with firebug loaded, it pauses in Firebug with the following screen shown :

[image: Image showing script subsection of Firebug with play button and program loading]

What is causing this, as it will not allow me to interact further with my site until I close Firebug? Is there a bug in my code?

Comment: Did you try F8 after it? Is there any message in Console?

Comment: F8 after and it works as normal - why is this? There are no messages in the console.

Comment: You should check the link Cheery mentioned in his comment on answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you have a breakpoint set on that line or possibly an error and break on all errors is turned on.

Go to breakpoints tab and remove all the break points and also set break on all errors to off.

Comment: As far as I know, You will see a big red dot on left if you have a break point.

Comment: @SKS you can break on events, without the 'red dot' http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#suspend